# SSL certificate verification works in Docker, not on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, rust

I've had an issue with my Kubernetes pod that has bothered me for weeks. I have a Rust web service running on my self-hosted Kubernetes cluster, and the other day, OpenSSL certificate verification suddenly stopped working (that is, without any changes to the physical or virtual machines or the template and Docker image).

The weird part is that when I run the Docker image on my machine – be it in Minikube or Docker Desktop – it works. The even stranger part is that it also works when I run it as a Docker container directly on the server, alongside the other Kubernetes-related Docker containers.

The Rust `reqwest` error that is thrown when I try to fetch data:

```
error sending request for url (https://google.com): error trying to connect: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1915: (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I have also tried running wget from inside the Kubernetes pod on the production cluster, without any success:

```
~ # wget https://google.com
Connecting to google.com (<my public ipv4>:443)
ssl_client: google.com: certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
wget: error getting a response: Connection reset by peer
```

From this, I have drawn the conclusion that the problem lies somewhere in my Kubernetes templates, although they do work on my machine (to be more specific, I have deployed the image with Helm). For anyone interested, [here is all of the source code](https://github.com/ThePicoNerd/mashed-potato/).

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I would never expect `google.com` to be `<my public ipv4>`; are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had been foolish enough to create a wildcard public DNS record for the domain of my cluster: `*.example.com` pointed to `example.com` while my cluster was configured with `k8s.example.com`.